# Why does PHP come out on top over Node.js when I benchmark them on a IO operation?

Tags: php, node.js, http, io

I'm running an benchmark with the apache benchmarking tool on PHP and Node.js, port 80 and port 8000 respectively. Node benchmark command below, swapping out the port when running tests on PHP:

```
ab -n 100 -c 100 http://localhost:8000/
```

What I'm doing in the programs is simply reading in a 10MB text file and then send that back to the client. To my surprise the PHP benchmark takes around 6 seconds and Node.js is way up at 13 seconds.

This is the text file:

https://github.com/jamesward/play-load-tests/blob/master/public/10mb.txt

This is the code for each:

**Node.js**

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var s = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/plain"});

    fs.readFile("./10mb.txt", "utf8", function(err, data) {

        res.end(data);

    });     


});

s.listen(8000);
```

---

**PHP**

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("./10mb.txt");
```

---

Am I doing something wrong in the Node code? Otherwise I'm pretty confused, one of the main selling points of Node was that it was fast in OI operations. What point am I missing?

Comment: The version numbers are going to be *critical* here. I'm assuming both PHP and Node.js are the latest version?

Comment: i don't think this question will attract useful answers, but rather a lot of speculations and some highly opinionated answers in the form of "well, because [x] simply stinks". you could try getting more detailed information about your node-script by reading some times *in* the script, seeing what parts exactly slow you down. could be that loading it into an variable and *then* sending it to the client takes more time, whereas PHP automatically optimizes the no-variable-one-liner?

Comment: Yes PHP 7 and Node LTS, 6.9.1

Comment: Putting the php file_get_contents return value into a variable first and then echoing the variable on a second line did not make it slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP will run multithreaded so some of the 100 requests will be in parallel.

Node.js is singlethreaded but asynchronous. Generally this trade-off is a win for Node.js since it will consume less RAM and incurs fewer context switches. In this case however you're reading a huge chunk of data (10mb) into RAM and then sending that out.

Memory operations in node.js are synchronous. So while both the file read and socket write operations are asychronous there is a huge memcpy in there that effectively blocks the interpreter.

The correct way to handle very large data in node.js is to use streams:

```
var s = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream("./10mb.txt");

    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/plain"});

    readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: As a side note - this also means that caching large data in RAM is counterproductive in node.js. It's faster to cache the data as a file and let the async I/O handle it. My rule of thumb is anything below 1MB is OK to cache in memory. Anything bigger should use temporary files or a database.

Comment: You're right! Using streams and having that stream created inside of each request like you have got there inside the handler to the request event makes it faster than PHP. I upped the original 100 requests on my benchmark test to 300 and PHP does it in 17 something seconds and node is at 16 seconds. If I only create the readstream once outside the request handler it handles all those requests at an amazing 400 milliseconds. Had to increase the max amount of event listeners for that one single readstream from 10 to 1000 (1000 worked, probably doesn't need 1000 listeners) Is this good practice?